# Wiener process - proof of independent increments

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I have defined the Wiener process to be a stochastic process $X_t$ with values in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $X_0=0$, the paths $t \mapsto X_t$ are continuous, and for any times $0<t_1<\dots<t_n$ and Borel sets $A_1,\dots,A_n \subset \mathbb{R}$:

$$
\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in A_1, \dots, X_{t_n} \in A_n) = \int_{A_1}\dots\int_{A_n}p_{t_1}(0,x_1)\dots p_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(x_{n-1},x_n) \; \textrm{d}x_1\dots \textrm{d}x_n
$$

where

$$
p_t(x,y) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2t}} 
$$

is the transition density. From this definition, how do I prove that for any $0=t_0 \leq t_1 \leq \dots \leq t_n$, the increments

$$
X_{t_1}-X_{t_0}, \dots, X_{t_n}-X_{t_{n-1}}
$$

are independent? In general, the only way I know how to show that two RVs are independent is to show that their joint density function factorises into the product of the marginals, but I can't see how to do that here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Direct from the fact that, for every $t$, $p_t(x,y)=q_t(y-x)$ for some suitable function $q_t$. (But note that each $p_{t_k}$ in your displayed formula should read $p_{t_k-t_{k-1}}$.)

Comment: @Did Ah yes, silly me. I've edited it. Still, how does this show that the increments are independent? Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: Did you try proving it for only two points $X_{t_0}, X_{t_1}$ (i.e. $X_{t_0} \perp X_{t_1} - X_{t_0} $) and instead of general $(A_i)$, try well defined sets?

Comment: @user3371583 Well, yes, I would tackle it by considering just two increments as you suggest. But I'm not sure where to start. And what do you mean by well defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First consider the case $n=2$. By definition, the joint distribution of $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ is given by

$$p_{t_1}(0,x_1) p_{t_2-t_1}(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 = q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(x_2-x_1) \, dx_1 \, dx_2$$

where

$$q_t(x) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}} \exp \left(- \frac{x^2}{2t} \right), \qquad x \in \mathbb{R}.$$

Consequently,

$$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp(\imath \xi X_{t_1} + \imath \, \eta (X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})) = \iint \exp(\imath \, \xi x_1+\imath \, \eta (x_2-x_1)) q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(x_2-x_1) \, dx_2 \, dx_1 \end{align*}$$

For fixed $x_1$ we substitute, $y_2 := x_2 - x_1$ and obtain
$$ \begin{align*} \mathbb{E}\exp(\imath \xi X_{t_1} + \imath \, \eta (X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}) &= \iint \exp(\imath \, \xi x_1+\imath \, \eta y_2) q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(y_2) \, dy_2 \, dx_1. \\ &= \left( \int e^{\imath \, \xi x_1} q_{t_1}(x_1) dx_1 \right) \left( \int e^{\imath \, \eta y_2} q_{t_2-t_1}(y_2) \, dy_2 \right) \\ &= \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \eta X_{t_1}} \cdot \mathbb{E}e^{\imath \eta (X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})}. \end{align*}$$

This finishes the proof for $n=2$. The general case is treated by induction.

Comment: Thank you. I did not think of taking the expectation of the exponential! Why do you need the $\imath$?

Comment: @TomOffer The proof shows that the characteristic function of the joint distribution equals the product of the characteristic functions of the marginal distributions. (And the characteristic function of a random variable $X$ equals $\mathbb{E}e^{\imath \, \xi X}$; that's why I need the $\imath$.)

Comment: Ooh. I'm with you now. Cheers! (I can't tag you for some reason so I hope you read this...)

Comment: @TomOffer You are welcome.

Comment: are you not assuming $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ has the same distribution as $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})$?

Comment: @badatmath No, why do you think so? $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ has clearly not the same distribution as $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})$.

Comment: In the first line you say $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ has distribution given by $p_{t_1}(0,x_1) p_{t_2-t_1}(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 \, dx_2 = q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(x_2-x_1) \, dx_1 \, dx_2$ and then you use the same density in $\mathbb{E}e^{i(\xi,\eta)^T (X_{t_1},X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})}$

Comment: @badatmath  The density of $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2}-X_{t_1})$ is given by $q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(x_2)$ whereas the density of $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ is given by $\tilde{q}(x_1,x_2) := q_{t_1}(x_1) q_{t_2-t_1}(x_2-x_1)$. In particular, they are not equal. What I am using in my computation is that $$\mathbb{E}f(X_{t_1},X_{t_2}-X_{t_1}) = \int \int f(x_1,x_2-x_1) \tilde{q}(x_1,x_2) \, dx_1 \, dx_2$$ (for any "nice" function $f$) which follows from the very fact that $(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ has density $\tilde{q}$ w.r.t Lebesgue measure. If you don't see that, then write first the left-hand side in the form

Comment: $\mathbb{E}g(X_{t_1},X_{t_2})$ for a suitable function $g$

Comment: I see what you mean now. Thank you for clarifying!